# Payflow percentage discount issue

Tags: paypal, magento-1.6

I am using Magento ver. 1.6.2.0 and Payflow Express checkout.
I am not able to continue to paypal payment when I use percentage discount coupon.

Its working fine with the fix amount coupon.

Its always showing me following error.

> PayPal gateway rejected the request. Field format error: 10431-Item amount is invalid.

I already tried to change the roundPrice decimal to 4 from 2.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: paypal takes the amounts rounded to 2 while magneto has upto 4. did you tried to round the magento amount to 2?

Comment: Initially in Magneto it was 2 but i found somewhere that it requires to change it to 4 , I tried both way , but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I fix it myself. I requested Patch from Magento from one of my Enterprise project PATCH_SUPEE-1474_EE_1.12.0.2_v1.sh and find and replace the code lines manually . This patch fixed my paypal discount issue but then it show the total mismatch issue , so after tracing more i found that Payflow is not passing shipping and tax amount, I added those lines in to Payflow NVP.PHP from Paypal nvp.php and finally its working fine for all the case.

You can get the updated files from here

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3udWHRsbBdAOEpPSmJocXA1TFE/edit?pli=1
```

Thanks

Comment: Paypal become work.